# How to save data of the updated table to another table in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I just started in Django, I'm developing a web-application that want to create a `Purchase Order` and `Masterlist`.
I started using the generic views and now I can create and update a Purchase Order. It has a `status` field of `Pending` and `Received`. If I created a new Purchase Order the default status is `Pending` and If I updated it to `Received` it should also save the data to `Masterlist` table. The thing is, it doesn't work. By the way, the `received` item should stay in `Purchase Order` table for history.

Since I'm using the generic views in Django.. I tried to put the `masterlist` table in the update view of the `purchaseorder` but It has error saying `No masterlist found matching the query`

Here is my class for the `UpdateView`

```
class PurchaseOrderUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = PurchaseOrder
    model = Masterlist
    fields = ['item_no', 'description', 'dimension', 'unit', 'quantity', 'cost', 'project_site', 'po_date', 'supplier', 'status']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.prepared_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

What I expect is, when I update the status field of my Purchase Order to received, it should also saved the data of it to Masterlist. Or If the item in Purchase Order exists in Masterlist it will update the quantity on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a get() which receive request parameter. Now in this function get data of the field and check If the status changed to received, Then code to update / 
save data in Masterlist.

To update / save you can create a common function update_or_create()

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Can i request for reference? I've been searching for this and can't tell which is which. Sorry I have still about 30% of idea in Django.

Comment: Have a look on this class - 
class PurchaseOrderUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
 model = PurchaseOrder
 fields = ['item_no', 'description', 'po_date', 'supplier', 'status']
 
 def form_valid(self, form):
  form.instance.prepared_by = self.request.user
  return super().form_valid(form)
 
  # This calls when post request comes
 def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
  status = self.request.POST.get('status')
  if status == 'received':
   MasterObject = MasterList(status='received')
   MasterObject.save()
  super().post() # call the parent post function

Comment: Got it sir. But is it okay to save it like this? : `item_no = self.request.POST.get('item_no') description = self.request.POST.get('description') dimension = self.request.POST.get('dimension') unit = self.request.POST.get('unit') quantity = self.request.POST.get('quantity') cost = self.request.POST.get('cost')  status = self.request.POST.get('status')` and then `MasterObject = Masterlist(item_no=item_no, description=description, dimension=dimension, unit=unit)`

Comment: Yes, It is absolutely fine.

If you get rid of your error by my answer. You can upvote my answer.

Comment: Is this wrong? `self.request.POST.get('id')` I can't get the id of the Purchase Order to save to Masterlist. By the way, thank you so much! I can't upvote your answer, it says I need atleast 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

Editing The Other table from the changes of the other table.
hello I think you can use the models save() function to do that. If you have two tables A and B and you want when you update one the atribute of the other changes, So long as the tables relate lets try like these.

```
class B(models.Model):
    atribute_2 = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
class A(models.Model):
    atribute_1 = models.ForeignKey(B,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    atribute_3 = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.atribute_1 == "pending":
           self.atribute_1.atribute2 = "Pending"        
        super(A, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```